# $x^3+3x^2+4x+5=0$ and $x^3+2x^2+7x+3=0$, how many common roots they have?

Tags: polynomials, roots

My attempt, 
Equate both, at the end you will get $x^2-3x-2=0$

That means $x=-1$ and $x=2$. But what after that. Please provide solutions as well.

Comment: Hint: You also need $x = -1, 2$ to be roots of both polynomials.

Comment: @Macavity but in that case x=2 will give both equations to be 33, however x=-1 is not giving that. Am I right?

Comment: Thats because your solutions to the quadratic are wrong.  $x=1, 2$ are the solutions.

Comment: @Macavity okay. Right. But after that?

Comment: The points common to the cubics also have to be roots of the cubic for being an answer.  Given that they are not (just substitute to check), there cannot be any common roots.

Comment: @Macavity Thanks that satisfies. But any idea why that happens?

Comment: No idea what to call cause and what the effect.  As mentioned in one of the answers below, the cubic polynomials are relatively prime (no common factors), so perhaps you can think of that as a reason.

Comment: @Macavity ok. Thanks. That clears a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Compute the $\gcd$ of the two polynomials to see that is $1$. Thus, no common (non-constant) factor, no common roots.

Comment: But I think factorising that would be terrible task.

Comment: @SherlockWatson, please look up Euclidean Algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Polynomials

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in your calculation (or a typo). $-1,2$ are not
the roots of $x^{2}-3x-2$.

Denote 
$$
p(x)=x^{3}+3x^{2}+4x+5$$
$$
q(x)=x^{3}+2x^{2}+7x+3
$$

and $x_{0}$ is such that 
$$
p(x_{0})=q(x_{0})=0
$$

then 
$$
p(x_{0})-q(x_{0})=0
$$

as well. This gives us 
$$
x_{0}^{2}-3x_{0}+2=0
$$

and since the zeros of the polynomial 
$$
x^{2}-3x+2
$$

are $1$ and $2$ those are the only possible values for $x_{0}$.

Note: 
$$
p(x_{0})-q(x_{0})=0\iff x_{0}^{2}-3x_{0}+2=0\iff x\in\{1,2\}
$$

But none are roots of $p,q$ and so those don't have any roots in common

Comment: @Macavity -already edited! :)

Comment: @Macavity - Yes, I looked at Andreas answer and I saw where I made the mistake and edited to correct it